# Generic SBJason parser reflects error on Xcode 4.5

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using SBJason parser to pull data from my server into my app but am getting this new error after upgrading to Xcode 4.5.

On this line:

```
- (void)maxDepthError {
    self.error = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Input depth exceeds max depth of %lu", maxDepth]; //This is where the error lies
    self.state = [SBJsonStreamParserStateError sharedInstance];
}
```

The error:

```
Format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger'(aka 'unsigned int')
```

Any pointers is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix error change format specifier to correct value for unsigned integer (`%u`)

```
self.error = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Input depth exceeds max depth of %u", maxDepth];
```